# A function or a macro for retrieving attributes of annotated strings

Tags: julia

I have strings with annotated attributes. You can think of them as XML-document strings, but with custom syntax of annotation.

Attributes in a string are encoded as follows:

`#<atr_name>=<num_of_chars>:<atr_value>\n`

where

- `<atr_name>` is a name of the attribute
- `<atr_value>` is a value of the attribute
- `<num_of_chars>` is a character length of the `<atr_value>`

That is attribute name is prefixed with `#` and postfixed with `=`, then followed by number that indicates number of characters in the value of the attribute, then followed by `:`, then followed by the attribute's value itself, and then followed by with newline character `\n`

Here is one example:

```
julia> string_with_attributes = """
some text
...
#name=6:Azamat
...
#year=4:2016
...
some other text
"""
```

Now I want to write a function or a macro that would allow me to call as:

```
julia> string_with_attributes["name"]
"Azamat"

julia> string_with_attributes["year"]
"2016"

julia>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Gnimuc answer, you could make your own *string macro* AKA **non standard string literal** if that suit your needs, ie:

```rb
julia> function attr_str(s::S)::Dict{S, S} where {S <: AbstractString}
           d = Dict{S, S}()
           for i in eachmatch(r"(?<=#)\b.*(?==).*(?=\n)", s)
               push!(d, match(r".*(?==)", i.match).match => match(r"(?<=:).*", i.match).match)
           end
           push!(d, "string" => s)
           return d
       end
attr_str (generic function with 1 method)

julia> macro attr_str(s::AbstractString)
           :(attr_str($s))
       end
@attr_str (macro with 1 method)

julia> attr"""
           some text
           dgdfg:dgdf=ert
           #name=6:Azamat
           all34)%(*)#:DG:Ko_=ddhaogj;ldg
           #year=4:2016
           #dkgjdlkdag:dfgdfgd
           some other text
           """
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "name"   => "Azamat"
  "string" => "some text\ndgdfg:dgdf=ert\n#name=6:Azamat\nall34)%(*)#:DG:Ko_=ddhaogj;ldg\n#year=4:2016\n#dkgjdlkdag:dfgdfgd\nsome other text\n"
  "year"   => "2016"

julia>
```

Answer (score 2):

seems like a job for regex:

```
julia> string_with_attributes = """
       some text
       dgdfg:dgdf=ert
       #name=6:Azamat
       all34)%(*)#:DG:Ko_=ddhaogj;ldg
       #year=4:2016
       #dkgjdlkdag:dfgdfgd
       some other text
       """
"some text\ndgdfg:dgdf=ert\n#name=6:Azamat\nall34)%(*)#:DG:Ko_=ddhaogj;ldg\n#year=4:2016\n#dkgjdlkdag:dfgdfgd\nsome other text\n"
julia> s = Dict()
Dict{Any,Any} with 0 entries

julia> for i in eachmatch(r"(?<=#)\b.*(?==).*(?=\n)", string_with_attributes)
         push!(s, match(r".*(?==)", i.match).match => match(r"(?<=:).*", i.match).match)
       end

julia> s
Dict{Any,Any} with 2 entries:
  "name" => "Azamat"
  "year" => "2016"
```

Comment: see my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @aberdysh  tricky but I think extending `Base.getindex` is a little bit overkill here, is this feature crucial to you? what would you do if you wanna match another pattern?

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out what I needed was to extend the `Base.getindex` method from `Indexing` interface.

Here is the solution that I ended up doing:

```
julia> 
function Base.getindex(object::S, attribute::AbstractString) where {S <: AbstractString}
    m = match( Regex("#$(attribute)=(\\d*):(.*)\n"), object )
    (typeof(m) == Void) && error("$(object) has no attribute with the name $(attribute)")
    return m.captures[end]::SubString{S}
end


julia> string_with_attributes = """
    some text
    dgdfg:dgdf=ert
    #name=6:Azamat
    all34)%(*)#:DG:Ko_=ddhaogj;ldg
    #year=4:2016
    #dkgjdlkdag:dfgdfgd
    some other text
    """

julia> string_with_attributes["name"]
"Azamat"

julia> string_with_attributes["year"]
"2016"
```